# iOS and push notifications-does not work in Xcode environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm not sure that title is clear. What's happening is that I have been working on the Push Notifications feature for my enterprise app. It has been working fine in the development environment, but I have migrated to the distribution version, and it works fine on the iPhone *if* the app is downloaded from the archived .IPA file on the server, but *not* if it is running from the directly installed version from Xcode. (i.e. through the iPhone connected to the Mac via USB.) And even if I stop the test run, disconnect from the Mac, and run the app as it is installed directly from Xcode, PNs do not come through. It's only if I reinstall the app from the server. Very strange.

I have all certificates properly created and installed, which shouldn't matter, I'd think.

Anyone have a clue why it's like this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Additional info: Same problem if I load it either way on the iPad. OK if downloaded, not if directly installed.

Edit 2: I figured it out. See my answer below.

Comment: maybe you have different environment with different bundle id?

Comment: Hmm. I'm trying to understand how that would happen. Could the bundle id be different between the test version and the distribution version?

Comment: oh yes, that must be. or your certificates are built for test not for production. you should check your bundle ids

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was sorta stupid on my part. Turns out the version installed onto the phone from Xcode is by default a development version, and I was using the distribution server configuration. Duh.